# В wp вывод архива только по месяцам?

Tags: php, wordpress

Нужно вывести отдельно сылки на архив по годам и по месяцам.

```
<?php wp_get_archives('type=yearly'); ?>
```

это выводит все нормально(только год)

```
<?php  wp_get_archives('type=monthly'); ?>
```

а это почему-то выводит год+месяц, как можно сдать, чтобы вывело только месяц без года.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Этот код полностью работает

```
wp_get_archives()

wp_get_archives( 'type=monthly' );
```

Все правильно, что monthly выводит еще и год т.к. будут повторяться месяца между годами

```
preg_replace( '/ [0-9]{4}/', '', wp_get_archives() );
```